# ¿Cómo guardar valores nulos o personalizado en un dateTimePicker en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, textbox, datetimepicker

Muy buenas a todos, tengo este problema si me pudieran ayudar, tengo un formulario que me registra datos de un "empleado", todo me guarda exitosamente en SQL Server, mi problema es que tengo un DateTimePicker para la fecha de ingreso del empleado, pero también tengo otro DateTimePicker para la fecha de retiro, como puedo hacer para que el segundo DateTimePicker(el de retiro) me guarde valores nulos? o aún mejor que pueda introducir un texto personalizado, como si se tratase de un TexBox, para que al momento de registrar un nuevo empleado no me guarde la fecha de retiro con la fecha actual (por defecto)sino, que guarde la cadena de caracteres personaliza, pensaba usar un TexBox, pero necesito que guarde fechas si se trata de un retiro. Gracias por leer.

Información adicional, uso Visual Studio y SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamentablemente los **DateTimePicker** que vienen por defecto en **Visual Studio** para aplicaciones **Windows Forms**, **no admiten valores nulos o vacíos**(nunca puedes borrar el texto de un **DateTimePicker**, siempre va a tener una fecha seleccionada). Puedes usar dos variantes.

**Variante 1**:

Usas el control **MaskedTextBox**(es un control diferente al **TextBox**).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te paras arriba del control marcas la flechita que te sale y das clic en **Set Mask...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta ventana te saldrán varias **máscaras o formatos**, en tu caso escoges **Fecha** que es el que te hace falta, das clic en OK y ya. Este control no es tan bonito visualmente como el **DateTimePicker**, pero si permite dejar el campo vacío, indicando que no hay ninguna fecha que establecer en él.

**Variante 2**:

Si de todos modos deseas emular el funcionamiento de un **DateTimePicker** pues te propongo lo siguiente, vas a poner en tu formulario un **MaskedTextBox** y vas a hacer lo que te expliqué anteriormente, posteriormente vas a añadir al lado de este **MaskedTextBox** un **DateTimePicker** y este lo vas a reducir hasta que solo quede visible la flecha desplegable del mismo, de modo tal que parezca un solo control cuando en realidad son dos, pero están bien juntitos. Al **DateTimePicker** en su **propiedad Format** le vas a poner **Short** para que la fecha salga en **formato DD/MM/YYYY**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que es un solo control, pero en realidad son dos bien juntitos, el que tiene el círculo verde es el **MaskedTextBox** y el que tiene el círculo rojo el **DateTimePicker** con su tamaño bien reducido. Posteriormente vas al **evento CloseUp** del **DateTimePicker** y añades este código:

```
fechaSolicitudMaskedTextBox.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

Lo cual quiere decir que cuando selecciones una fecha en tu **DateTimePicker** en el **MaskedTextBox** se pondrá la fecha seleccionada, y ya tendrás el funcionamiento deseado.

Espero te sirva cualquier cosa me avisas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias busque mucho en la red y no encontraba lo que necesitaba,el MaskedTextBox era algo que desconocia totalamente, muchas gracias ya pude hacer lo que queria.

Comment: Agradeceria tu voto y que me aceptes la respuesta